# dice games in the mac app store?

Tags: macos, app-store, store

I have a mac app.  Logically, it could be considered a dice game.  One of the listed categories for my LSApplicationCategoryType key is public.app-category.dice-games.  But when I go to the store and look at the list of categories, I don't see one for dice games.

So if I use public.app-category.dice-games for the key, what can I expect to happen with my app in the store?

Comment: Starting a bounty -- it may be a dumb question, but I really want to know the answer :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant DICE games! -> http://www.dice.se/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, what the hell.

Dice games are, to me, a subset of the casino games category (usually - it might also be a kids' game, or you could make an educational game that uses dice to teach addition to children).  So, if it's a supported category, Apple might just shove it into a broader category like casino games or whatever the app seems to be for.  If in doubt, though, you really ought to contact Apple about it (whether or not you can do that, I don't know).  Since the Mac App Store doesn't actually show it as a category, it might be a deprecated value, too.

At any rate, I can't give you a concrete answer, since I'm not Apple.

Answer (score 4):

As best I can determine, there is a category type for Dice games.

I would suggest starting with:

http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/itunes-connect.html

and reading through

http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

If you search for LSApplicationCategoryType in this PDF, there is only one result.

It will take you to some information which says that you will need to select the primary and secondary categories for your app. The primary category would be Games and Dice is a valid selection for the secondary category.

What you will also see is the following:

> The list of categories you can choose
>   to define in your info.plist is the
>   same as what is available for Mac OS X
>   apps in iTunes Connect.

To find this information, I went to the [Mac Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action) and clicked on the [Submitting to the Mac App Store](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/documents/submitting.html) link. In there I found **public.app-category.dice-games**

It would seem that you can specify that yours is a dice game at every point you need to.

Comment: Definitely in there.  I wonder if the reason it's not in the Mac App Store is because nobody has actually submitted a dice game yet?

Comment: I did a search for Yahtzee in the store and found Maxi Dice Gold...so there is at least one dice game in the store.